# VBA macro for reading cell values from linked tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, caa

I have Access application that stores CAD model parameters and connects via VBA macros to CATIA to input that parameters values into real model (CAA Automation)

This is how simplified relations looks:
[Database relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxv1G.png)

There are different forms for body, part and assembly.
In assembly form when there is the same name of parameter in liked tables control source is being named Body.A an Part.A, when different control source is as the name of parameter (B1, D)

definition is made for each lenght

```
set lenghtX = parametersX.Item("CATIA parameter name") 
'type is lenght, so program CATIA and it's method doesn't matter
```

so reading and sending values by

```
lenght1.value = B1
'left side lenght in CATIA
'ride side control source name in MS Access
```

or

```
lenght2.value = D
```

WORKS

but to read from linked (by it's control source name, how it was done in code before)

```
lenght3.value = Body.A
```

or

```
lenght4.value = Part.A
```

NOT

does anybody now how to get values from linked tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, `Body.A` and `Part.A` are names of controls.

While you usually can refer to controls by just stating their name, this doesn't work if they have characters that aren't allowed in a variable name like a dot or a a space.

You can refer to them explicitly through the controls collection.

```
lenght3.value = Me.Controls("Body.A").Value
```

I'm not familiar with CAA or CATIA, though, so I might have overlooked something obvious on that part.

Comment: WORKS. in use looks like:
        Length3.Value = Forms("Assembly_formname").Controls("BODY.A").Value